# How to access Google News headline links

Tags: axios

I'm doing an axios call on an Google News article url, like:

Google News link:
"https://news.google.com./articles/CBMiiwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5zdGlyaXBlc3Vyc2Uucm8vbGVjdGlhLWRlLXJ1c2EtcGVudHJ1LWNhLXByZXR1cmlsZS1zdW50LW1hcmktZ2F6cHJvbS1udS1zZS1ncmFiZXN0ZS1zYS1vYnRpbmEtYXByb2JhcmlsZS1wZW50cnUtbm9fMjEyNzEwMC5odG1s0gE2aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc3RpcmlwZXN1cnNlLnJvL2FtcC5waHA_YXJ0aWNsZV9pZD0yMTI3MTAw?hl=ro&gl=RO&ceid=RO%3Aro"

The result of the call is the same Google News listing page from where I've got the link, although when manually accessing the link in the browser, I get a redirected to the publisher website/url.

Any idea on why this happens and what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `"curl -L -v {your url}"` in a command prompt, if this works, which it should, check the user agent in the headers.

Use this user agent in the axios custom headers.

For example:

```
const optionsCurl = {
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'curl/8.4.0',
    Accept: '*/*',
  },
  redirect: 'follow',
};
```